# Does anyone have a good reference on calculating contour integrals around the unit circle (numerically or otherwise)?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, contour-integration

I am looking for a reference that will help me calculate contour integrals around the unit circle or other curve. I have a particularly ugly function which isn't likely to have a nice closed form so I can't find any references which solve similar problems.

In my case, I need to integrate a contour around the unit circle where the denominator contains the fourth root of a polynomial of degree $12$. It happens that $6$ of the $12$ roots are inside the unit circle and have a known value. I also know the value of the other $6$ roots outside of the unit circle but I do not think they are as important.

Does anyone have a source that will help me deal with this problem? Can anyone sketch a method of calculating this? I have tried integrating from one root to it's conjugate assuming the other sections of the contour would have no contribution but I have not received correct results.

Can I assume that there is no contribution from the circles that go around the zeros of the polynomial?

Comment: The function you are integration is a *fourth root*, so something like $1/\sqrt[4]{f(z)}$? Have you heard of the residue theorem?

Comment: @KCd I do not know how to use the residue theorem in this instance because there are only branch point singularities instead of poles.

Comment: I agree such usage would be problematic; I was just checking if you knew it. Is the polynomial itself nasty (you say 6 of the 12 roots are "known", and are the ones outside the unit circle "known" too)?

Comment: @KCd I know all of the roots but why are they important if they are outside of the contour? The polynomial is simple enough and all of the roots can be represented not-so-nicely with nested radicals. For what its worth, each of the roots has nonzero imaginary part and comes with a conjugate pair.